# Are there netcat-like tools for Windows which are not quarantined as malware?

Tags: windows, networking

I used to use netcat for Windows to help track down network connectivity issues. However these days my anti-virus software (Symantec - but I understand others display similar behaviour) quarantines `netcat.exe` as malware.

Are there any alternative applications which provide at least the following functionality:

- can connect to an open TCP socket and send data to it which is typed on the console
- can open and listen on a TCP socket and print received data to the console

?

I don't need the 'advanced' features (which are possibly the reason for the quarantining) such as port scanning or remote execution.

Comment: curl.exe comes with windows 10 1803 and above.

Comment: what about busybox for windows? if in alpine it is solo, it is at least harmony for windows, I carry it with me and use busybox.exe nc tar ash (and vi) on a daily basis

Answer (score 32):

[ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/) seems to be exactly what you're looking for. It's an implementation of [*netcat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) available on the official [Nmap](https://nmap.org/) site with the port scanning feature removed. Doesn't raise any virus alerts either.

From the ["Ncat Users' Guide"](https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/):

> Ncat is our modern reinvention of the venerable Netcat (nc) tool
>   released by Hobbit in 1996. While Ncat is similar to Netcat in spirit,
>   they don't share any source code. Instead, Ncat makes use of Nmap's
>   well optimized and tested networking libraries. Compatibility with the
>   original Netcat and some well known variants is maintained where it
>   doesn't conflict with Ncat's enhancements or cause usability problems.
>   Ncat adds many capabilities not found in Hobbit's original nc,
>   including SSL support, proxy connections, IPv6, and connection
>   brokering. The original nc contained a simple port scanner, but we
>   omitted that from Ncat because we have a preferred tool for that
>   function.

Comment: This got flagged as a virus by my overzealous AV (Windows Defender, I believe).

Comment: I also encountered the same...download was blocked as a virus.  If you're willing to take a long route, you can install it from Cygwin as the `nc` and `nc6` packages.  I then just copied it from the install test machine (which we use/abuse to collect all spurious software packages) to my local machine.  Seems to work fine.  I only needed the `nc.exe` and the `cygwin1.dll` from the install test machine's cygwin

Comment: @RexBarker Note that the `nc` tool which is installed in __cygwin__ is a different implementation than the `ncat` tool which is installed with nmpap. For example the command `nc -v -l xxx xx` on cygwin doesn't print the ip of the remote host or when a connection is establish by a remote client. On the contrary the command `ncat -v -l xxx xx` gives you this important details. This is why I prefer to use __ncat__ instead of __nc__. Another advantage of `ncat` is that probably it is not black listed by an AV software as reported by Andrew.

Answer (score 22):

The quick answer here is to use the built in Telnet program from the CMD command line.

the command is...

```
telnet hostname.domain.com 80
```

The above example will connect you to the hostname on port 80.  you can use it on just about any port you need to check out.  This is extremely handy for troubleshooting SMTP and ESMTP issues.

Comment: Yes telnet is useful, but only solves half of the problem.

Comment: This will only allow me to do the first of my bullet points, won't it? Also doesn't telnet expect some sort of handshake communication from the socket it connects to?

Comment: You no longer have telnet on win vista.

Comment: But you can install it, according to (for example) http://www.adamsdvds.co.uk/tutorials/vista/telnet/telnet.php...

Comment: AFAIK it does both.  You can connect it to a port and look to see what the output is.  I do this all the time.  Connecting to the port also works like a champ.  You can also run telnet from the command line by itself.  This gets you to the telnet command line.  You can tweak the setting to echo locally by typing "Set Localecho"

Comment: Matthew: telnet doesn't have any special handshake; there are, however, some special control characters. But telnet is fine for most of the usual protocols (POP3, IMAP, SMTP, HTTP, IRC...)

Comment: According to the telnet spec. (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html) there can be option negotiation between the telnet client and server just after connection. Are you saying that in practice Windows telnet client doesn't do this?

Comment: Every time I have needed to force it to locally echo the characters I am typing, that is how I did it. Keep in mind you are not connecting to a telnet port as long as you use a port other than 23.

Comment: @Axxmasterr my version of telnet (Windows XP) doesn't seem to support a 'listen' mode.

Comment: Since the link from Matthew doesn't work anymore, telnet still exists in Vista and 7, it just has to be installed in the Control Panel/Turn windows features on/off. AFAIK it doesn't even require the installation DVD.

Comment: Telnet can't do UDP testing like netcat can (e.g. for testing VPN connectivity)

Comment: It doesn't do both. Telnet cannot act as a server.

Answer (score 15):

http://joncraton.org/blog/netcat-for-windows

This person ran into the exact same problem; read till the end for the version compiled without remote execution.  I downloaded and extracted these on two systems running 'Symantec Endpoint Protection'.  While the netcat on this page was removed and quarantined when run, the 'rodneybeede' version linked to near the end of the page tried to connect to the desired port, and wasn't quarantined.

Comment: Yes, note that this site has a download with a "non -e" version that apparently is more friendly for virus scanners.

Comment: This netcat is ancient and does not have IPv6 support.

Comment: and it is also blocked by CrowdStrike as "malicious" :(

Comment: Virustotal says Detection ratio:  27/73 so it is the same in this regard as the original...

Answer (score 13):

I discovered that **[MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)** for Windows has the **nc** (netcat) command, as well as many other Unix commands, like **ls**, **ps**, and **kill**.

I wholeheartedly recommend MobaXterm, especially if you are familiar with both Unix and DOS.  For me, there was nothing to install; it's just one executable that opens a terminal window in Windows that accepts many Unix commands.  Since I frequently use both Unix and DOS and often use one to connect to the other, MobaXterm for Windows is an extremely useful tool for me.

(Sorry if this sounds like an advertisement; I don't work for nor am I affiliated with MobaXterm.  A friend recently introduced it to me and it made certain tasks so much easier for me.)

Comment: I believe this is just the "cygwin" netcat, and installed to a temp folder, so not accessible outside "MobaXterm" [however, it does work from inside its shell].

Answer (score 4):

Even if it seems otherwise, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is easy to use. You can setup it easily to listen to a specific port.

[image: wireshark]

Another tool is [nmap](http://nmap.org/) which again, I find easy to use. It will tell you much about open ports on a remote machine, so you can use it troubleshoot connectivity issues. Just nmap www.google.com from command line, or from included gui interface.

[image: nmap]

[image: nmap]

Just give them a try.

Comment: Will these tools let me 'open and listen on a TCP socket and print received data to the console' (the second bullet point)?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a screenshot of tcp capture from Wireshark. In 9 minutes i've downloaded it, installed it, started a capture, and gave it a screenshot.

Comment: But isn't Wireshark capturing data sent between two already executing networked processes? I really want to be able to start up the application to listen on a port as a server (as I could with netcat) so that I can debug client applications.

Comment: Wireshark will not allow you to communicate with the server you are connected to, nor will it listen on socket for incoming connnection.  It is a packet capture tool, not quite what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Will WireShark let me capture data between two processes running on the same machine?

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch   If the processes communicate with pipes then no. If the processes communicate via 127.0.0.1 then wireshark for linux allows it.. Wireshark for windows might have an issue with 127.0.0.1 and you'd then need to use rawcap to see packets on 127.0.0.1 which is a bit like tcpcap, it's a command line wireshark.  Anyhow these things are packet sniffers, not comparable to nc in function.

Comment: I've always used netcat (nc) as a "telnet to anything" tool, a much lighter-weight and structured wget/curl, a telnet that doesn't cry when not really talking telnet. A super light way to experiment with and pretend to be an httpd server without nginx. A simple one-liner echo server. The association with a packet capture tool like tcpdump or wireshark confuses me.

Answer (score 4):

If you need netcat, you can whitelist netcat.exe in your anti-virus program.

You may also want to download a current version, which is called [ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/) and can be found in the [nmap distribution](http://nmap.org/download.html).

Comment: unfortunately "ncat" (the command line executable provided by the nmap distro) doesn't seem to be a drop in replacement for the unix "nc" command [different command line parameters] <sigh>...you have to get a true "netcat" somewhere else [or use cygwin]

Answer (score 4):

You can download Ncat - [Netcat for the 21st Century](http://nmap.org/ncat).
It seems to be a modern version of NCat, it is actively supported, and, most important, it had a **0/48 detection ratio** at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/).

[Portable version](https://nmap.org/dist/ncat-portable-5.59BETA1.zip) or from [NMap Windows installer](http://nmap.org/dist/nmap-6.40-setup.exe) - disable anything else from the install wizard:

[image]

Comment: It is at 26/68 currently, detected by most popular AV software. "Live" link to check: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5e107ea10383110bd801fb7de11f59ee35f02b8e1defcadf34c0e3e769df9341

Answer (score 1):

There is now also separate 'ncat' static build available at http://nmap.org/dist/ncat-portable-5.59BETA1.zip